# Monitor Web-Surfing (Browsing History) Remotely and Silently

Tags: remote-control, browser-cache, browsing, network-monitoring

I want to know what websites are visited on one of my family's computers.

The user of that laptop can browse the Internet incognito (now cache, no history like in Google Chrome' incognito mode).

I have an access to that computer via TeamViewer (remote control app), so I can install soft. But I cannot use TeamViewer to do something frequently (only once or twice a month, otherwise it will look suspicious that I conjure something so often).

What is a good approach to monitor browsing history remotely and silently? I just need to know visited websites.

Answer (score 1):

Log activity on the router. This way no need to access their computer. Just sniff what they are doing by enabling logging in your home's router. Most router's now have this feature.

Comment: cannot do that, I am not in a home network, I am in a different country. That is my I use TeamViewer. And of course I cannot go to the router's site so apparently via TeamViewer when the user will see what I do

Comment: You're probably going to be breaking all sorts of laws then. :-)